# Can't start NFS server on docker ubuntu 16. 04

Tags: docker, nfs

I am trying to start NFS server using docker. I've created Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
ENV TERM linux
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install --assume-yes \
    software-properties-common wget
RUN apt-get install --assume-yes \
    pkg-config \
    curl jq vim \
    nfs-kernel-server

RUN mkdir /var/nfs/general -p   
RUN chown nobody:nogroup /var/nfs/general
```

Then I did following commands:

```
sudo docker build -t nfs-ubunta .
sudo docker run --privileged -it nfs-host-ubuntu:latest /bin/bash
```

I added this line to **etc/exports**:

```
/var/nfs/general 172.17.0.3(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
systemctl restart nfs-kernel-server
```

ANd I got this error:

```
Not starting NFS kernel daemon: no support in current kernel.
```

Output of lsb_release -a

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

Comment: Maybe you should check how [cpuguy83](https://github.com/cpuguy83) does something similar here: [github.com/cpuguy83/docker-nfs-server](https://github.com/cpuguy83/docker-nfs-server). Check his `Dockerfile` and the `init`, `stop` and `setup` files...

Comment: Yes, it can help. Thanks @tgogos